# return a value and result set from stored procedure in @NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to get both a return count and a result set back from a stored procedure, 
in my @NamedStoredProcedureQuery, that return count is total count of result rows.

i need this return count for my pagination of stored procedure in my code.

Is it possible with @NamedStoredProcedureQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the entire result set or is it paginated? If you are getting the entire result set and are using Spring Data, you can just use the returned List<> size as the return count and the List will be your result set. Spring Data uses the following model:

```
public interface MyDao {
    List<MyModel>  myNamedStoredProcName(
        @Param("param1") double param1, 
        @Param("param2") double param2
        );
}
```

When autowiring MyDao, you can get the list back with a function call.

If you are using an actual ResultSet object, you would have to loop through the entire result set to get the count, then do a resultSet.beforeFirst() before you go on to using it.

Comment: it is paginated, so i need the total count for my pagination in code.